# Snakemake MissingInputException

Tags: snakemake

We have always run our Snakemake pipelines through Amazon S3.

```
snakemake --default-remote-provider S3 --default-remote-prefix '$s3' --use-conda
```

However, we need to run our Snakemake pipeline locally for a new experiment.

```
snakemake --use-conda
```

The pipeline works great when running with `--default-remote-provider S3 --default-remote-prefix '$s3'`; however, when we try to run locally we get:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 226 of /usr/local/eclipse/snakemake_eclip/rules/rep_element.smk:
Missing input files for rule compress_parsed:
    output: rep_element_pipeline/IN1_BET_S35_R1_001.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed.gz
    wildcards: sample=IN1_BET_S35_R1_001
    affected files:
        rep_element_pipeline/IN1_BET_S35_R1_001.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(41): `conda run snakemake --use-conda --cores 36` failed. (See above for error)
```

Below are the two rules that are causing the error. I'm fairly certain it has something to do with the local wrapper `temp(local('{full_path}' + 'rep_element_pipeline/{sample}.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed'))`.

`{full_path}` is an absolute path where the files at the beginning of the pipeline are located.

```
#Create final rep element parsed file
rule merge_parsed:
  input:
    'rep_element_pipeline/AA.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/AC.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/AG.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/AN.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/AT.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/CA.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/CC.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/CG.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/CN.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/CT.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/GA.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/GC.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/GG.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/GN.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/GT.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/NA.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/NC.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/NG.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/NN.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/NT.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/TA.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/TC.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/TG.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/TN.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed',
    'rep_element_pipeline/TT.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed'
  output:
    temp(local('{full_path}' + 'rep_element_pipeline/{sample}.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed'))
  conda:
    '../envs/rep_element.yaml'
  params:
    fp=full_path
  shell:
    'perl ../scripts/merge_multiple_parsed_files.pl {output[0]} {input}'

#Compress sam.parsed
rule compress_parsed:
  input:
    'rep_element_pipeline/{sample}.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed'
  output:
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/{sample}.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed.gz')
  params:
    fp=full_path
  conda:
    '../envs/standard_eclip.yaml'
  shell:
    'pigz -c {input[0]} > {params.fp}rep_element_pipeline/{wildcards.sample}.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed.gz'
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of rule `merge_parsed` is:

```
temp(local('{full_path}' + 'rep_element_pipeline/{sample}.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed'))
```

but the input of `compress_parsed` is:

```
'rep_element_pipeline/{sample}.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam.parsed'
```

The string `{full_path}` is in the first but not the second. Isn't this an issue or am I missing something?

Besides, I would avoid concatenating file paths with `+`. Better to use `os.path.join` which takes care of adding the correct separator.